# Cannot Compile Java project

Tags: java

I'm trying to compile an old java program that I wrote on BlueJ but now trying to run it without it.
It's a simple code that uses `java.awt., java.io.*, and java.util.*` if that makes a difference.

I have the java JDK downloaded and all variables set. I can run a different program that I coded without an IDE (Its an entire project file with its own lib file tho if that makes a different).

**If i run it with javac filename.java i get this error:** error: file not found: filename.java
Usage: javac  
use --help for a list of possible options

**If i add -cp it says:** error: no source files

and I've tried several other things that all resulted in the same or similar errors.

My best guess is java cant locate its lib folder but that shouldn't be a problem considering a JDK and JDR and downloaded and set

Comment: I suggest you solve it by importing your project into an IDE again (whether Eclipse, BlueJ, IntelliJ IDEA or something else).

Answer (score 2):

If

```
$ javac filename.java
```

fails with the message

```
error: file not found: filename.java
...
```

the compiler is telling you that it cannot find the source file that you told it to compile.

Why?  Here are the most likely explanations.

- The file isn't in the working directory where you ran `javac`.
- You got the filename incorrect.  Maybe you mistyped it?  On some systems, filenames are case sensitive.
- Possibly it is a permissions problem; e.g. you are trying to compiler using an account that doesn't have access to read the source code file.

---

> My best guess is java cant locate its lib folder.

Nope.  If that was the problem, `javac` wouldn't tell you that the file that you were trying compile was not found.